# Exception in @Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath() when passing a query string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

When I'm passing a query string to my "Details" page, @Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath() looks at the last parameter in my URL, which in MVC is the ID that I'm passing, instead of the page name. It ends up not showing anything at all. Is there a way to programmatically set the SiteMapPath() in my controller when it gets to the "Details" view?

_Layout.cshtml:
@Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath()

Mvc.sitemap:

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Search" controller="Vendor" action="Search" key="Vendor">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Search Results" controller="Vendor" action="SearchResults" key="Search">
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Details" controller="Vendor" action="Details" key="Details"/>
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
  </mvcSiteMapNode>
```

Note: The "Search" and "SearchResults" pages work perfectly.

/Vendor/Search works.

/Vendor/SearchResults works.

/Vendor/Details/418 does not work.

**Edit:** Turns out all I needed was to add preservedRouteParameters="id" to my mvcSiteMapNode, so

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Details" controller="Vendor" action="Details" key="Details" preservedRouteParameters="id" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to index these pages in search engines, you should use a dynamicNodeProvider to create a node for every possible Id (presumably from a database).

```
public class VendorDynamicNodeProvider 
    : DynamicNodeProviderBase 
{ 
    public override IEnumerable<DynamicNode> GetDynamicNodeCollection(ISiteMapNode node) 
    {
        using (var db = new MyContext())
        {
            // Create a node for each album 
            foreach (var vendor in db.Vendors) 
            {    
                DynamicNode dynamicNode = new DynamicNode();
                dynamicNode.Title = vendor.Name;
                dynamicNode.ParentKey = "Vendors"; // Attach to a node that is defined somewhere else
                dynamicNode.RouteValues.Add("id", vendor.Id.ToString());

                yield return dynamicNode;
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

On the other hand, if you are building pages to edit the data (CRUD operations) and/or you do not want the pages indexed by search engines, you can use preservedRouteParameters (as you have already discovered) to force a single node to match every possible id.

Typically when you do this, you will also need to use the SiteMapTitleAttribute and the FilteredSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider to adjust the appearance of the menu and SiteMapPath. See [How to Make MvcSiteMapProvider Remember a User's Position](http://www.shiningtreasures.com/post/2013/09/02/how-to-make-mvcsitemapprovider-remember-a-user-position) for a complete example.